# Set string comparison for assembly

Tags: c#

I wanted set `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` for **all strings**  compared in my assembly. Is this possible? I know, that I can set this parameter every time I compare strings

```
string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

but this is not a case. I can even write my own `IEqualityComparer<string>` but this is similar to example above.

Comment: You can write an extension method wrapper for this, naming it accordingly.

Comment: That would be confusing I think. In one code path two strings are equal but in another code-path they aren't...automagically...

Comment: This won't make all strings entirely case-insensitive, for example dictionary keys would still be case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to make changes to the source code, you can use the ["Caseless" Fody addin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caseless.Fody) and configure it in the `FodyWeavers.xml`:

```
<Caseless StringComparison="InvariantCultureIgnoreCase"/>
```